# How to write range of price close on pinescript

Tags: range, pine-script, pine-script-v5

How do I write a range on pinescript?
I am using the code below, what I mean is to write a bar_index range and check if within that range, price is rising or falling, example, from bar index 12 to bar index 3, then using `ta.rising` or `ta.falling`to see if it's rising or falling within that range

```
p_range1 = high[3:6]
p_range2 = high[2:0]

going_up = ta.rising(p_range1)
going_down = ta.falling(p_range2)

if going_up == true and going_down == true
   lable.new(//to comment the a kind of retest has been made)
```

i can use `ta.rising(close,5)` but this checks from index 0 to index 4 but i want it to check in-between, example, from index 3 to index 5

> to create a code that shows a retest after a cross over has been made but not necessarily that price must touch the moving average but to show that a retest price pattern was made

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have made a better explanation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must write a function to do that :

> the ta.rising Test if the `source` series is now rising for `length`
> bars long.
> RETURNS true if current `source` is greater than any previous `source` for `length` bars back, false otherwise.

```
Rising(bar_index_start, bar_index_end) =>
    response = false
    if bar_index_end - 1 < bar_index_start
        response := na
    else
        max = 0.0
        // Search for the maximumn value before bar_index_end
        for i = bar_index_start to bar_index_end - 1
            if close[bar_index - i] > max
                max := close
        // Determine if it's rising
        if close[bar_index - bar_index_end] > max
            response := true
```

Answer (score 0):

Copilot:

```
// Custom function to check if price is rising within a specified range
Rising(bar_index_start, bar_index_end) =>
    var float max = na
    for i = bar_index_start to bar_index_end - 1
        if close[bar_index - i] > max
            max := close[bar_index - i]
    rising = close[bar_index - bar_index_end] > max
    rising

// Example usage:
p_range1 = high[3:6]  // Specify your desired bar index range
p_range2 = high[2:0]
going_up = Rising(3, 6)
going_down = Rising(2, 0)

// Now you can use 'going_up' and 'going_down' in your strategy logic
if going_up and going_down
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Retest Pattern")
```

Comment: Please don't post any generative AI output here.